# getting url from variable that calls picture of current page, not working. Only displays everything instead of url

Tags: php

I am trying to echo an image to the background like so

```
$product_pic = get_the_post_thumbnail($pid, 'full');
$pid = $result[0]->productID;

<style>
    .product-pic-bg{background-image:url("<?php echo  $product_pic;?>")}
</style>
```

It doesn't work. All I get is `.product-pic-bg{url""}` in the console.

When I dump the $product-pic I get:

[image: background]

What do I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_post_thumbnail` function returns the post thumbnail image tag as a string. 
Use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` function instead to get url.

```
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($pid, 'full');
```

Comment: thanks very much. Guess I cant reuse the $product_pic. This worked.